#  Drupal views structure

Tags: php, drupal-6, drupal-views

i've a Drupal theory/strategy related question. First i want to say that i'm very new to the drupalling world, so this question can be quiet stupid. I'm trying to develop/make a part of a site that has the following structure:

- (level one) virtual_exhibitions: shows an overview of exhibition categories.
- (level two) themes, places, people: which is an exhibition category.
- (level three) love, belgium, napoleon: which are exhibitions, every one of there will give a list of photos related to the exhibition subject.

now i created a new node-type: virtual-exhibition.
and i created a vocabulary: exhibition-categories.

now to create the structure i used views:

- one view to list all the nodes from a selected category with a link to the node.
- one view to list all the categories.

now i was wondering if this is the drupal way to do this, or are there better alternatives. This is working, but i'm not sure if this is the right way.

Another question related to this, i want to use clean urls:

- virtual_exhibitions
- virtual_exhibitions/themes, virtual_exhibitions/places, ...
- virtual_exhibitions/themes/love, virtual_exhibitions/places/belgium, ...

The first one is easy, i can configure this in the views UI. The second one is a bit harder because the categories can have special characters like a ' or a , etc. So i need a raw version (as can be used in path auto) in fact it would be best that my default link of the vocabulary term redirects to this view. because the url of the vocabulary term is very easy to configure using path auto and then i can just use the vocabulary term url in stead of always building it manually.

The reason why i'm using a view for the second level is because it needs a custom layout and as far as i know it isn't possible to style a vocabulary-term of a specific vocabulary. When you style it this style will be used for all the vocabulary-terms.

i hope my description is a bit clear and that somebody can give me some remarks on how i best do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look on views arguments.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i'm using the arguments already. But when i make a view for my second level with the arguments enabled. I need to build the url manualy in the first level to get to the second level. I can just do /virtual_exhibitions/[name-of-the-category] but then i'm not using a raw version, i get something like this: /virtual_exhibitions/Thema's for example but the clean version should be /virtual_exhibitions/themas (themas is a dutch word). I can do this manually in the template of the view but i don't know if this is the right way to do this.